# How to use StringTemplate for code?

Tags: string-manipulation, templates

Say, I want to write a MMA script using `StringTemplate`, so I can insert additional pieces of code / expressions wherever `TemplateSlot`s appear. It is a bit unclear to me, however, how I should handle these slots. For example the template

```
tmp = StringTemplate[
  ToString[
    Unevaluated[
      Pi/2 + "`a`" + 2
    ],
    InputForm
  ]
]
```

gives

```
tmp[<|"a" -> 1|>]
(* Pi/2 + "1" + 2 *)
```

That is, it looks like the parameter `1` is substituted as a `String` whereas it should be a number. This is not the case, however. What actually happens is, that `1` gets inserted, but the quotation marks in the template remain. So **how should I declare `TemplateSlot`s in my `StringTemplate`?** It should work with any MMA code inside the `Unevaluated`.

Comment: Perhaps ``OutputForm["`a`"]`` instead of ``"`a`"``?

Comment: I'd not use StringTemplate here, check what happens for `"a"->-1`.

Comment: @CarlWoll: Yes, this seems to work! Thanks! I'd accept it if you post this as an answer. Much easier than I thought :-) 
@Kuba: There does not seem to be any problem with `-1` (after applying `ToExpression` in the end).

Comment: @JEM_Mosig if there is ToExpression then why strings at all, why not go with TemplateObject? And if string step is needed then `"Pi/2 +   - 1"` does not look well.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Carl's method you can use:

```
StringTemplate["Pi/2 + `` + 2"]["`a`"]
```

> ```
> "Pi/2 + `a` + 2"
> ```

so

```
templ = StringTemplate[
   StringTemplate["Pi/2 + `` + 2"]@"`a`"
];

templ @ <|"a" -> 2|>
```

> ```
> "Pi/2 + 2 + 2"
> ```

but for `"a" -> -1` you will get

> ```
> "Pi/2 + -1 + 2"
> ```

so I'd suggest full `TemplateObject` mode:

```
TemplateObject[
    TemplateExpression[
        ToString[Unevaluated[Pi/2 + TemplateSlot["a"] + 2], InputForm]
    ]
] @ <|"a" -> -1|>
```

> ```
> "Pi/2 - 1 + 2"
> ```

or

```
TemplateObject[
    Hold[Pi/2 + TemplateSlot["a"] + 2]
  , CombinerFunction -> (ToString[#, InputForm] &@*Apply[Unevaluated])
] @ <|"a" -> -1|>
```